# Are windows phone storage secure from external access?

Tags: c#, security, windows-phone-8, storage

I am building an application for Windows phone 8 which have some Assets currently stored in the installation directory of the app.
Since those need to be inaccessible from evil users, I'd like to know if:

1. there is a storage folder which is secure and can't be accessed using tool like isolation storage tool
2. if no, what could be a good way to make the asset secure? should i encrypt them? there are other ways?

Hope I made my question clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

During development your data can be accessed by other developers via Isolated Storage Tool (you can use fake data during development). But after application is installed from Marketplace it is not simple to access to an isolated storage of your application. In common case an application isolated storage is completely inaccessible for users. But of course it doesn't mean that your data is completely secured and encryption is a good point to protect your data. Follow by this link to get more info concerning data encryption in WP8 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh487164(v=vs.105).aspx