# How to update data file in wp8

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-phone-8

I'm quite new to this, so please bear with me if the answer is obvious.

I'm planning an app with employee data. It's only purpose is to be able to search for employee data, read only and data will (originally) reside in an .xml file

However, employees come and go, so which approach would be the best, to keep the data file updated?

It's simply a question of where to place the data file in WP8's localstorage so that it can be replaced with a newer file and how to accomplish this operation.

No SD-card on the phones.

And preferrably, no server involved if possible. Just a plain delete old file, add new file.

There is a lot of limitations afaik, presumably because of security reasons, which is fine with me, but I'm getting more and more confused reading posts about the subject.

As I haven't found any, I might suspect that it's not possible and that the easiest way is to update the app in Windows Phone store and ask the users to get the updated app from there.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: keeping employee data on a phone....what could possibly go wrong....

Comment: A lot, if the data file included personal information. But it don't :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about IsolatedStorage.
from here: [Are windows phone storage secure from external access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16983297/are-windows-phone-storage-secure-from-external-access)

During development your data can be accessed by other developers via Isolated Storage Tool (you can use fake data during development). But after application is installed from Marketplace it is not simple to access to an isolated storage of your application. In common case an application isolated storage is completely inaccessible for users. But of course it doesn't mean that your data is completely secured and encryption is a good point to protect your data. Follow by this link to get more info concerning data encryption in WP8 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh487164(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Thanks lavysh. The data is already available publicly, so I have no concerns with regard to safety in this context. What I'm looking for is an easy way to update the list of employees, e.g. once a month.

Comment: You need to add some update service to your app. This service will check  when a new data are available

Comment: @lavysh - do you have any specific keywords I could use to search the net - for descriptions, examples etc?

Comment: - you can use WCF service and call a special method in this service, which will return info about new data. - or use Push Notifications+ Azure.